# How to debug DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, debugging, logging, orm, dbix-class

I was recently working on a Perl project that required me to use DBIx::Class as the ORM to interact with a database. One of the things I found most annoying and just time consuming was just trying to debug and understand what was happening.

I was especially frustrated with and error I was getting `Column 'XXXXXX' in where clause is ambiguous` and I figured out what was causing this error. It was down to the fact I was requesting columns from 2 different tables which where joined on the XXXXXX attribute and in the WHERE clause the column wasn't being aliased. This lead to DBIx::Class not knowing which column to use.

The most frustrating thing was not knowing what DBIx::Class was doing, leading me to have many doubts about where the error was coming from.

How to efficiently debug this kind of `DBIx::Class` errors?

Answer (score 4):

You enable debugging by setting the `DBIC_TRACE` environment variable to `1` or a filename.

That's documented at the very top of [DBIx::Class::Manual::Troubleshooting](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/view/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Troubleshooting.pod#Tracing-SQL)

Comment: There is also `DBIC_TRACE_PROFILE`, which when set to `console` produces pretty colourful SQL.

Answer (score 3):

So I knew what the error was, but I didn't know exactly where it was being caused. If this was plain old SQL I would've simply added the aliases myself but I didn't know how to do that in DBIx::Class. Moreover, I had no clue what SQL query was actually being executed, which made things even worse.

That's when I found out about the `as_query` method (https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#as_query) which, when logged, prints out the SQL query that DBIx::Class executes. **LIFE CHANGER**. Saved me from so much trouble and gave me exactly what I needed. Shortly after I was able to solve the issue.

Moral of the story: if you're having trouble seeing what DBIx::Class is doing, use this and save yourself from countless headaches.